# Using SQL to edit salary based on job id

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Table: EMPLOYEES

Columns:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, PHONE_NUMBER, HIRE_DATE, JOB_ID, SALARY, COMMISSION_PCT, MANAGER_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID
```

My current output from the Employees table looks like this:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID LAST_NAME                 JOB_ID         SALARY
----------- ------------------------- ---------- ----------
        205 Higgins                   AC_MGR          12000
        149 Zlotkey                   SA_MAN          12500
        201 Hartstein                 MK_MAN          13000
        102 De Haan                   AD_VP           17000
        101 Kochhar                   AD_VP           18000
```

My SQL:

```
SELECT employee_id,
last_name,
job_id,
salary
from employees
where (job_id like '%VP' OR
Job_id like '%MAN' OR
Job_id like '%MGR')
AND (salary < 6000 OR salary >11000)
order by 4
```

I need a way to display the salaries before and after a raise, but I also need to be able to give different raises for different job_ids. For example, giving a raise only to the VPs and not to the managers, or giving the VPs a bigger raise than the managers.

Comment: Can you provide desirable output as well?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a CTE which says who gets what; then (outer) join it to the original table. Something like this:

```
SQL> with raise (job, raise_pct) as
  2    (select 'CLERK'  , 10 from dual union all
  3     select 'ANALYST', 20 from dual
  4    )
  5  select e.empno, e.ename, e.job, e.sal old_salary,
  6    e.sal * (1 + r.raise_pct/100) new_salary
  7  from emp e left join raise r on r.job = e.job
  8  order by e.job, e.ename;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB       OLD_SALARY NEW_SALARY
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         3000       3600
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         3000       3600
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           1100       1210
      7900 JAMES      CLERK            950       1045
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           1300       1430
      7369 SMITH      CLERK            800        880
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         2850
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         2450
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         2975
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT       5000
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        1600
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        1250
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        1500
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        1250

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```